# Array of audio files

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, audio

I am trying to loop through an array of audio files, but each time it reads an index in myAudio, I receive a

> myAudio.load is not function

Why is this happening?

```js
    $("#playBtn").click(function(){
        isPlaying = true;
        myAudio.play();
        console.log("playBtn is working");
    })        

      var myAudio = [
        'sound/animals.mp3',
        'sound/maps.mp3',
        'sound/misery.mp3'
          ];
      index = 0;


      myAudio.load();
```

```css
#playBtn{
    cursor: pointer
      }
```

```html
<div id="playBtn">play</div>
```

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/6xsqoLcn/ ?

Comment: Are you trying to make an audio playlist  ? If so, take a look at this tutorial, the result is awesome. http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-audio-player-with-playlist/

Comment: Your `myAudio` is an array. There is no `load()` method on an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#playBtn").click(function(){
    isPlaying = true;
    console.log("playBtn is working");        

  var myAudio = [
    'sound/animals.mp3',
    'sound/maps.mp3',
    'sound/misery.mp3'
      ];
  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * myAudio.length) + 1);
  var src = myAudio[rand];
  var tag = document.getElementById('audio');
  tag.setAttribute("src", src);
  tag.load();


});
```

Comment: `myAudio` is an array. There are no `load()/play()` methods on an array.

Answer (score 1):

You needs set the source for each audio file **before** using the load function.

For example:

```
 var src = (the audio source location)
 var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
 audio.setAttribute("src", src);
 audio.load();
```

In this case, your sources would be the values in the myAudio array, and you would need to set a different src depending on the audio you needed to play.

Comment: @Roh Did this answer help? If so, I'd love it if you would accept :)